# Symfony Form CollectionType with predefined/static rows

Tags: forms, symfony

I am trying to create a CollectionType form with predefined/static rows (**not a dynamic form w/JS**).

This does what I want:

```php
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('titles', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => TextType::class,
    'data' => ['en' => '', 'de' => ''],
]);
```

but this doesn’t work (it results in no rows at all in the form):

```php
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('titles', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => TextType::class,
]);
$formBuilder->get('titles')->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = ['en' => '', 'de' => ''];
    $event->setData($data);
});
```

In the end, I am looking for a simple form like so:

```html
<form name="form" method="post">
    <div id="form">
        <div><label>Titles</label>
            <div id="form_titles">
            <div><label for="form_titles_en">En</label>
                <input type="text" id="form_titles_en" name="form[titles][en]">
            </div>
            <div><label for="form_titles_de">De</label>
                <input type="text" id="form_titles_de" name="form[titles][de]">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I need the second approach for various reasons. Does anyone have a solution?

FYI: My current platform is Symfony 5.4 and Php 8.1 but I would like this solution to work with Php7.4 as well as Symfony 6+

Comment: Do you have an entity this is bound too? It doesn't look like it. In that case you don't need the CollectionType, just create your own form type with the fields you need and have the `data_class` as null.

Comment: Thank you @Bossman ! I guess I lost my head and wasn't thinking straight :) I appreciate you pointing me in the proper direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @Bossman for giving me direction. This is how I solved the problem.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use App\LocaleProvider;

class TranslationCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    private LocaleProvider $localeProvider;

    public function __construct(LocaleProvider $localeProvider)
    {
        $this->localeProvider = $localeProvider;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($this->localeProvider->getSupportedLocaleNames() as $name => $value) {
            $builder->add($value, TextType::class, [
                'label' => $name,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then add to the form:

```php
$builder->add('Titles', TranslationCollectionType::class);
```